# I got an error in my code; now guess the error message and how to fix

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [auto-smell the phrase “it doesn't work” and ask user if enough info given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/auto-smell-the-phrase-it-doesnt-work-and-ask-user-if-enough-info-given)
>   [Encourage users to provide code when relevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/encourage-users-to-provide-code-when-relevant)

In SO we get a lot of question on the lines,

> I got an error message, HELP!

Those questions, strangely enough, do not include the error message itself, and if they do, they do not include the code the error message refers to. (It actually helped me improve my mind reading skills.)
There are some common phrases involved that I think the SE engine can detect and, at least, give a warning to the user saying that he needs to make sure he has:

1. relevant code, with the line causing the error being clearly marked
2. the error message

It seems to be affecting mostly new users, so I would probably do the check only on users with a reputation lower than, for example, 1000.

Comment: possible duplicate of [auto-smell the phrase "it doesn't work" and ask user if enough info given](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91040/auto-smell-the-phrase-it-doesnt-work-and-ask-user-if-enough-info-given), [Encourage users to provide code when relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/encourage-users-to-provide-code-when-relevant), [When asking questions, suggest to provide vital information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97807/), [Add requirements for a tag (maybe a template?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16843/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I agree there should be a pop up warning when a user posts some text related to error message and reputation cap for that may not be 1000; but may be up to 200-300. Because IMHO, user gets matured when points reaches till there.

Also, if the user can be prompted to put error in block quotes then it will be an added advantage

Comment: +1 for putting error inside a specific tag. Can make developers life easier.